# How to get property of object dynamically in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Say for example I have the following object...

```kotlin
val ob = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
```

...and I want to select a property from this via a dynamic variable. `ob.<property>` would work normally but what if I didn't know `<property>` at compile time?

Is it possible to run something like `ob[<property:str>]` (as is the case in javascript, python etc) in kotlin?

Comment: This is called reflection. There are many questions about this subject already on here. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

Comment: Also: it's best to avoid using reflection unless there's no other way.  It's slow, fragile (as many errors which would otherwise be spotted at compile-time must be handled at run-time), hard to read, and hard to refactor.  It's great for compile-time tools, frameworks, plug-ins, &c; but for general-purpose coding there's usually a better approach.

Comment: you can have the expected objects implement a common interface

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, there is a nice library `kpropmap`. We use it on production because we just need to have a `Map<String, *>`, but I wouldn't recommend using it for accessing fields.

https://github.com/rocketraman/kpropmap
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.rocketraman/kpropmap

After adding a dependency you can just write

```
val map = propMapOf(obj)
val name = map["name"]
```

However it'd much better if you were able to cast the `obj` to some known type and access the property statically

```
(obj as? SomeInterface)?.name
```